# Does Background check contains information regarding visa processing as well

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, background-check, visa

I have accepted the offer from a company and now interviewing with other company.
A - company of which I have accepted the offer
B - Company for which I am interviewing

I am a F-1 student and company A have asked my details to start the visa proceedings for H1-B. My joining date is in mid Feb. They are looking to apply for H1-B in April I believe. If I get the offer from B, would it come in background check that A have processed for my visa, and I had accepted offer from them. And How it can affect my job opportunity with company B and what are other possible implications ?
I have also interned with company A so, i will be providing employment details as well to background agency.

Answer (score -1):

Employers pay significant amounts of money to employ H1B candidates.  This is not merely showing up on Monday and getting a desk assignment.  Keyword search this brings up fees that range in the $2500 to $4000 range, depending on nature of the employment.

Therefore, having two companies doing this is complicating things. You should let the second company know what's going on, and if they accept you they will have to start the H1B process over, or take over sponsorship from Company A.